# How can I get the name of the name of the current Service Fabric application?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to get the name of the Service Fabric application where my code is running?

For example, my ApplicationParameters file has this:

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/mytestapp" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
```

I want to retrieve "mytestapp" and use it in my code, but I haven't found anything that would let me do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ApplicationName is present as a string (unfortunately not a URI) as a property on the CodePackageActivationContext.

```
// System.Fabric.CodePackageActivationContext
public string ApplicationName
{
    get;
    internal set;
}
```

CodePackageActivationContext is present on the ServiceContext that every service is passed in its constructor. Example from stateful services.

```
public StatefulService(StatefulServiceContext serviceContext)
    : this(serviceContext, new ReliableStateManager(serviceContext, null))
{
}
```

If your service is a guest or a container or something that doesn't use the ReliableServices API, then passing the name explicitly as a config setting is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I tried communicating the above `ApplicationName` between projects (Stateful to Stateless in my case), but it was surprisingly painful, to the point it was impossible because there is *inconsistency* in the value due to the different VM's and nodes being constantly changing.

I also tried communicating between projects by setting a value on some (static) variables of an external project, that didn't work.

Lastly I also tried writing the application name to a text file, but this only worked temporarily, because each node keeps an async copy of the text file.

**My solution** was to make use of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Fabric_ApplicationName")`, which worked perfectly.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration).

I hope this helps.